# Problem setting up branch in subversion

Tags: linux, svn, branch

The folder structure is as follows :

```
/home/src/repositories/svntest/branches
```

and access to the repository is `svn://ip.address/svntest`
I am trying to create a new branch in my repository using

```
svn copy trunk \ branches/new-branch
```

while in svntest folder

and it shows the following error:

```
svn: 'branches' is not a working copy
```

`trunk` folder contains the folders

```
BOOK/  bootscripts/  edguide/  patches/  scripts/
```

and `branches` folder is empty

I can access the repository, make changes, etc., users are set correctly.

What could be the cause of this error?

Comment: "while in svntest folder" - you have a complete checkout of trunk and all of your branches??

Comment: I'm very new to version control in general, so I don't know what problems it could bring. I tried full paths too, with the same result.

Comment: With the same result, i.e. "is not a working copy"? Then you're doing something wrong: using full URLs should not involve a working copy at all. Can you show us the exact line you're using? You don't need a backslash in the middle like you have in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the full URLs for trunk and your branch

```
svn cp svn://ip.address/svntest/trunk svn://ip.address/svntest/branches/new-branch
```

From inside a checkout you can also use the `^` notation

```
svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/new-branch
```

If you really do have a full check-out of svntest (i.e. with trunk and branches directory) then what you have (without the backslash) ought to work, although changes on this scale are a lot easier to do on the server without having to manage large checkouts.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$ svn copy svn://ip.address/svntest/trunk svn://ip.address/svntest/branches/new-branch
```

In most development activities you will check out only a single branch or trunk, not the repository root, so performing the copy on the server is more useful.